# fixed positioning with min-width affecs content when scroll page left to right

Tags: html, css, position

I have a header in my HTML which has to be fixed to stay at the top of the page. This works fine with no no problems:

```
header,footer{
    position:fixed;
}
```

But I want to have the min-width set, so the width cant be to small. I tried using min-width which works. When the window reaches that with the content inside my header stays where it is. But when the page is scrolled left to right the content never moves. It stays off the side of the page.

```
header,footer{
    position:fixed;
    min-width:800px;
    width:100%;
    background:#000;
    left:0px;
    display:block;
    z-index:10;
}
header{
    top:0px;
    height:100px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#FFF;
}
.login{
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    text-align:right;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    top:10px;
    font-size:14px;
}
.logo{
    height:90px;
    width:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
.logo img{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
.body{
    width:100%;
    min-width:800px;
    height:3000px;
    background:red;
}
footer{
    height:30px;
    bottom:0px;
    box-shadow:0px -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}


<body>
<header>
    <div class="logo"><img src="assests/logo.svg" /></div>

    <div class="login"><a href="#">LOGIN</a> <a href="#">REGISTER</a></div>
</header>
<div class="body"></div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
```

But when the header/footer is positioned 'Absolute' I can see my content when scrolling. There is a jquery method which works:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        $('header').css('top',$(window).scrollTop() + 'px');
    });
});
```

But css would be a lot cleaner and less 'jumpy'

Comment: That's what `fixed` means, it is fixed and will not move.

Comment: could it be done with jquery then, keep setting the top to the browers top when the page is scrolled?

Comment: Right now I can think of a javascript solution, only, so yes. It is possible. There might be some CSS solution though.

Comment: It works with jquery but css would be cleaner, thought this wold have been easier in css though

Comment: Can you link to the page you are talking about? it is hard to guess the issue from code alone

Comment: ill create a fiddle, it on localhost atm

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/awpc4m0t/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzjs89j5/   this one is working with jquery